# Are there safety concerns travelling by bus from Sofia to Istanbul?

Tags: buses, turkey, bulgaria

I am comparing flying from my location directly to Istanbul or flying to Sofia and from there taking a bus to Istanbul -- that is about half the price of flying all the way there.

Is it safe to go by bus? What should I know about the trip?

I see the tickets are available everyday. Shall I buy online or I could buy there? Is it possible a bus would get cancelled due to small number of passengers?

Comment: we can't answer "is it safe" but we can give you information you can use to make that decision yourself. What is safe for a 20-something man, or a small group of people, might not be for a 14 year old girl travelling alone. What is safe for someone who speaks local languages and looks like the locals might not be for an obvious tourist who can't understand what people are saying. And so on.

Comment: anyhow there is difference between two different routes as a safety manner and there is nothing to do with age  and etc. For example, if I asked you is it safe to go bu bus from berlin to amsterdam by bus more than from islamabad to delhi?

Comment: By "safe" do you mean "safe from threats to your person," or are you including "safe from possible logistical disruption"?  Do you plan to cross back from Turkey to Bulgaria?  I have a feeling that this might be a bit fraught given your name, but maybe I'm overreacting to what I've read (I've never crossed that border myself), and in any event you should not have too much trouble assuming you have a visa and proof that you recently left Bulgaria to travel to Turkey.

Comment: @Phoog Thanks. I have valid resident permit of a schengen country so i think no problem for bulgaria maybe. Also i can enter turkey without restriction and stay 90 days even due to my nationality no problem. Yes i meant threats or so. I do not want to turn back